# Hard-panned audio audible in both speakers

Tags: android, windows, matlab, audio, wav

I wasn't sure what SE site to ask this in, and Google isn't helping.

I generated the audio whose waveform is shown below in Matlab, with completely different signals in the left and right channels. But I've found that no matter how I try to listen to it (on my Dell XPS 15 Windows 10 laptop as well as on my Pixel 3 phone, with wired and wireless headphones), both channels are audible on both speakers. The audio levels are different on each side, so it is slightly panning (not mono), but it is not hard-panning as designed.

If I just feed the channels simple sine waves with different frequencies, it pans just fine. But this more complex signal won't pan.

What's up with this? Is it impossible to hard-pan some signals now due to some driver-level BS that mixes the channels? Or can I force it to pan as intended?

[image: Generated audio file]

Comment: if each of the shown signals are in either the left or right channel then simply bump up/down the volume of each channel to do the panning  ...  there is no behind the curtain combining of channels

Comment: @Scott Stensland The top one is the left channel, the bottom one is the right channel. Only one is in each channel.

The image is a screenshot of the generated WAV file opened in Audition in order to verify that the channels were split as intended.

If I set VLC to play only the right or left channel, it sounds as I would expect. But when it's set to stereo, both tracks are audible in both headphones.

Comment: I'm guessing "BS". I'm also wondering where a good place to ask this might be. SO is rather restrictive on question format. Maybe a more dsp-oriented site would have subscribers that know if some sort of "helpful" bs has been implemented for stereo and what those algorithms are. E.g. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/, https://www.dsprelated.com/, https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/ If you get to the bottom of this, I for one would appreciate your posting an answer here!

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Thanks! I'll see if I have time to repost it there later this week, and I'll update here if I get a good answer.